# When a circuit with three lights goes from series to combination, with one on the main loop and two on different branches, does power in branches $↓$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I am considering a circuit with three light bulbs. When a series circuit goes to a series-parallel circuit with one light on the main loop and two on different branches, the total resistance decreases by $1/2$ (because the two on the branches go from having a total resistance of 2 to 0.5, and $\dfrac{3}{1+0.5}=2$), doubling the total current, although the current in the branches is split in half, making each branch's current the same as in a series circuit. And since the total resistance of the branched part is half of one light, it uses 1/3 of the total of voltage (because $V*(0.5/1.5)=v*(1/3)$), just like one of the three lights in series. And this would mean the lights on the branched parts of a series-parallel circuit have the same amount of $V$ and $I$ as they would in series. Is this correct?

In class, in this series-parallel setup, when all the bulbs were screwed in the two on the branches were not lit (though must still have had electricity flowing through, just with not enough power). This makes me think my thinking above is wrong since the power must be less in the branches of the series-parallel circuit for the lights to be not glowing.

Comment: (a) "Is this correct?" Yes, if we assume that each bulb has a fixed resistance. But note that the voltage across the third bulb (the one in series with the parallel combination) is twice what it was when the three bulbs were connected in series. So we'd expect the third bulb to be brighter than the others when connected in the less straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) "Is this correct?" Yes, if we assume that each bulb has a fixed resistance. But note that the voltage across the third bulb (the one in series with the parallel combination) is twice what it was when the three bulbs were connected in series. So we'd expect the third bulb to be brighter than the others when connected in the less straightforward manner.

(b) A filament bulb *doesn't* have a fixed resistance. The greater the voltage applied across it the greater the current, but the current doesn't rise in proportion to the voltage. The resistance, that is the quotient voltage/current, increases as the applied voltage is increased. This is because the filament (metal wire) is getting hotter. The resistance is likely to be several times larger when the filament is at its working voltage than when only a very small voltage is applied.

I'm afraid that this invalidates your calculations. For example the resistance of the bulbs in the parallel combination will be less than that of the third bulb, which carries twice the current of the bulbs in the parallel combination. The voltage ($V=IR$) across the bulbs in parallel will therefore be *less than* half that across the third bulb. This is consistent with your observed results.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying the voltage across a bulb increases, with the current through it staying the same, as the bulb loses heat through the filament at an increasing rate? (Because if the rate of heat loss was constant then the amount of voltage used would be constant I think.) Also, would this not happen to all of the bulbs the same way, keeping their resistance values equivalent to each other, and therefore their respective voltages the same, just decreasing the current everywhere?

Comment: No, he did not say that the current stays **the same** when the voltage increases. Rather that it increases less fast than the voltage drop.  See my detailed answer as an edit of my initial one. Not enough room in a comment.

Comment: @Nathan (a) " So you're saying the voltage across a bulb increases, with the current through it staying the same..." No: if you increase the voltage across a filament bulb the current through it must increase. But it increases more slowly with voltage as the voltage (or current) increases. (b) This is because the *temperature* of the filament is increasing and free electrons encounter more resistance from vibrating atoms. (c) Rate of heat loss is pretty much irrelevant. (d) I can't understand the last sentence of your comment

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is right, and I don't understand why the bulbs were not lit, if they were lit in the case of series.

Your thinking is right, but a bit roundabout. The clearest way is to treat the two cases separately.

Series : Let the resistance of a bulb be R. The resistance of 3 bulbs in series is 3R. For total voltage V the current in the circuit, the same in each of the three bulbs, is V/(3R).

Series parallel : One bulb (resistance R) followed by two in parallel (resistance R/2) is 3R/2. Total current in the circuit V/(3R/2)=2V/(3R). This is the current in the single bulb of the main loop.
But in each bulb of the **branched part** the current is half this total thus V/(3R) just as in the case of the three bulbs in series.

So these bulbs should light up exactly as much as in case of the bulbs in series, but less than the single bulb in the main loop in the second case, which supports a current twice as strong.

I hope this is now clear to you.

---

EDIT

No, Philip Wood did not say that the current stays **the same** when the voltage drop increases. Rather that it increases less fast than the voltage drop. Or expressed differently, that the voltage drop increases **faster** than the current. So since the current in the single bulb in the main loop has to be **exactly twice** the current in each of the parallel branches, the voltage drop has to be **more than twice** the drop on these branches. So **more than** 2/3 of the total, leaving **less than** 1/3 for the drop on each of the bulbs of the parallel branches. Contrariwise it is exactly 1/3 for each bulb in the series case. But one does not know **exactly** how much less than 1/3 in the mixed case. There is no way to compute exactly the values without having **much, much more information**. One cannot expect of you to compute the exact value. But that can explain why there was not enough voltage drop for these bulbs to be lit.

The only answer you were **supposed to find** is that the current was the same. It is just a pity that the effect Philip Wood mentioned was so large in that case that the difference was clearly visible. They should have used bulbs with a smaller effect that would not show in such a strong way.

Comment: Thank you. This helps, though I still have no idea how the two were not lit (and yea they were lit in the case of series), but how the brightness of the bulb in the main loop increased makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: If you are satisfied, please accept one answer by clicking on the quote mark near the answer you prefer. You can also upvote one or both answers.